# Using an ASP.NET server control in a SQL Server 2005 reporting .rdl file

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, servercontrols, rdl

How would I embed an ASP.NET server control on a SQL Server 2005 Reporting file (.rdl)?

I am using the design view to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last time I checked you can't.  You're limited to code that generates images, like bar codes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. SQL Reporting Services can generate reports in a variety of formats -- HTML, PDF, XLS, CSV, and so on. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET other than the fact that you can use the ReportViewer web control to emit a report rendered in HTML format.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you might be able to use parameters to pass information into the report from the web page containing the report viewer.